# sort buddy list in real time 1:1 chat with pubnub react sdk

Tags: pubnub

I am trying to design a real time in-app chat for social application using PubNub. I found that the best architecture to do so for one to one chat with PubNub is detailed in this article http://pubnub.github.io/pubnub-design-patterns/2015/03/05/Inbound-Channel-Pattern.html

now my next problem is I have to display the list of users in the chatting window, how can I sort this list with the users who have sent messages latest at the top and the ones who have not interacted for a long time in the bottom. if I start fetching message from the inbound channel, I will have to always traverse inbound channel to the beginning every time a user has logged in, this will be a resource expensive call and also is not feasible if we have large user base and heavy message volumes.

I will also be using PAM to control authorization of users to read / write on channels.

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed a great blog entry!
If you are in hybrid mode, so you do use a replicate channel for History feeding anyway, then I would use that same channel and intercept it the content with a function and simply store in the channel Object the list of latest visitors ordered, by the latest showing first, you can even add any extra info you would like to it. Then, any time a user can access the Object values from a REST function to PubNub, so as to retrieve the "hybrid channel" associated Object values (stored earlier) and send that list that is always updated to the Chat user. This has an advantage: if you do not want to retrieve messages until a user taped on one of the contacts in the contact list to avoid pre-loading, then you would load no messages for any channel, except maybe the first user, but then its always less to load from History then all messages from all of the channels, and its always available, before fetched, so fastest.